# generate URL (without anchor tags) in mvc 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

i need to generate a link based on a controller and action but with no anchor tags, ie just generate something like this

http://www.stackoverflow.com/myfavorite/website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Url.Action rather than Html.ActionLink

Example

```
<%= Url.Action(new { controller = "myfavourite", action = "website" }) %>
```

Will give you the 'myfavorite/website' part, which you can prepend with your hostname if required.

Comment: thanks i had to modify it a bit but got it working with <%= Url.Action("website","myfavourite") %>

Answer (score -1):

Simply, you can write your own helper:

Html.Action(string action, string controller)

and customize result URL via String.Format()